# PHP Fatal error: Call to protected method FormValidator::setError() from context ''

Tags: php, class, closures, currying

consider my poor class:

```
abstract class FormValidator
{
    private $error_objects = array();

    protected function setError($entry_name,$err_msg)
    {
        $this->error_objects[] = 
            new FormValidatorErrorObject($entry_name,$err_msg);
    }

    protected function setErrorCurry($entry_name)
    {
        $_this = $this;
        return function($err_msg) use($entry_name,$_this)
        {
            return $_this->setError($entry_name,$err_msg);
        };
    }

    public function countErrors()
    {
        return count($this->error_objects);
    }

    public function getError($index)
    {
        return $this->error_objects[$index];
    }

    public function getAllErrors()
    {
        return $this->error_objects;
    }

    abstract function validate();
}
```

I use it in the implementing class like this:

```
$setError = $this->setErrorCurry('u_email');
    if(empty($uemail))
    {
        $setError(uregform_errmsg_email_null);
    }

    if(!filter_var($uemail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $setError(uregform_errmsg_email_invalid);
    }
```

and that results in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to protected method FormValidator::setError() from context '' ...
```

Question: is there a way to make the closure "inherit" the class context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not natively. [This manual note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#98384) suggests a rather cumbersome way of using reflection and a wrapper class to give closures private/protected access functionality though.

Comment: I checked that and it seems to work but nobody will ever use it because obviously it costs too much in terms of performance. Thank you anyway, that was a very educational read.

Comment: @fabio: Yep, guess my point was that you can't do this easily. Unfortunate, really.